# How to check whether a particular widget is show or not in the sidebar?

Tags: wordpress, templates, widget, sidebar

i want to code something in my post template. So, is there any way to check whether a widget that i want to show will be shown in sidebar or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the WordPress function `is_active_widget()`. It might be what you are looking for:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_active_widget/.

Answer (score 0):

You can add condition like this

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) : ?>
<div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```